# Is it allowed to update the UI while running in the background on iOS7?

Tags: ios

Up to iOS6, iOS would terminate an app that tried to update the UI during a long running background task. This has changed with iOS7. It just works and - if you look at the documentation about NSUrlSession and background fetching - is actually encouraged in order to update the snapshot of the app in case the user switches to the task manager.

Soooo...I tried that: create a long running task and kept on updating the UI. Works like charm. Is this something I should not do? Any official statement from Apple somewhere?

Comment: You say its "actually encouraged" but then ask is it something you should not do?!?

Comment: It's encouraged for NSUrlSession background transfers. There are no statements about long running background tasks.